# Cannot Get /index.html VS Code

Tags: javascript, html

I was doing a page trasition exercise and in the vídeo the person created two more html files and ended up with three: index.html, about.html and pricing.html. but the html files that were work before now just keep giving me the error "Cannot Get /index.html", "Cannot Get /about.html", "Cannot Get /pricing.html" and the problem seems to be with the / that are put before the html names, whoever, if i remove the / then the trasition showned in the vídeo doesn't occurs.

And also, just to finish it, my script.js has those three dots under the Swup() part and i don't kwon if this disturb my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="node_modules/swup/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
            <h1>This is the home page</h1>
        </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

(The code is the same for all of the html files. only thing that changes is the "home" in h1 that become "about" and "pricing")

```
const swup = new Swup()
```

Comment: Try access them manually and see what's going one,  e.g : htttp://your-url/about.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fact that the "/" links it to the root; if you just run the file directly in a browser, it wouldn't work, as the "root" is the drive. I personally use the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension, as it makes the project directory the root (using `localhost:3500`), mimicking an actual website.

Comment: I use Live Server as well but even then the error still occurs.

Comment: Are the html files at the root of your VSCode project? As in, not inside any other folders. If they are (say it's inside a folder named `demo1`), you need to use that in your links (for example, `/demo1/index.html` instead of what you have)

Comment: I will try it tommorow and i'll let you know if it worked or not.